# Obtener foto de teléfono usando Image Picker en Vue-CLI con Capacitor

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, ionic, cordova

Estoy intentando hacer un picker de imágenes de la galería, en un proyecto que he creado con VUE-CLI y le he agregado Capacitor manualmente.

Estoy utilizando esta documentación: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker

Ya ejecute estos comandos:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker
npm install @ionic-native/image-picker
ionic cap sync
```

El último no me funciono "ionic cap sync" porque no tengo instalado Ionic, no se si podría agregarlo de forma segura a mi proyecto de Vue-CLI sin romperlo?

Veo que en la documentación aparece solo una forma de hacerlo con React, pero no se de que manera podria hacerlo con Vue-CLI ya que no aparece, estan bien los comando que puse o cuales tendría que poner?

Y de que manera podria mandar a llamar a realizar el "picker" de imágenes de la galería desde un método de un componente en Vue?

Comment: `"cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker"`, amigo, instalaste la version de `cordova` tienes que fijarte si hay version de ese plugin para `capacitor` y si la hay entonces en la misma documentacion te aparecera como hacer la misma instalacion del plugin pero usando `capacitor`, lo otro es que, estas confundido, desde un inicio deberias haber instalado ionic y creado el proyecto diciendole que quieres usar vue, `ionic` soporta `vue`, `angular` y `react`, se supone que no deberias haber realizado el proyecto directamente con `vue`.

Comment: Si no mas bien haber instalado `ionic` y desde los comandos propios de ionic decirle que querias crear un proyecto usando `vue`, porque como digo ionic soporta multiples frameworks, tu estas aparentemente haciendo el proyecto en `vue` como tal y no como tal usando `vue` en `ionic`.

Comment: Ese es el problema que ya no puedo migrar el proyecto, por eso preguntaba la manera